# How to get operator of files when I monitor a folder?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-ndk

I'm trying to use FileObserver to monitor a folder and I need to get the operator who modifyed files. But when capturing an FileObserver event, I can only get event and file path by onEvent() methed.

What can I do to get the operator real time?

Comment: Sorry, the kernel doesn't make that information available in the inotify mechanism which FileObserver is built on.  And unless you are root, an lsof type of approach of trolling through /proc to see who has an open fd to it won't work on processes owned by other app userid's.

Comment: Tks. But even if I can get root permission, use "lsof" which is depending on /proc is not a real time way. The file operator may release the file fd before I get information from /proc. I've considered this way, but I think it may not work stable ?

Comment: Yes, you end up with a race condition.  But what else do you want to do - modify the kernel with the patch to have inotify report pids that has been floating around?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not modify the kernel, so it seems that I have to look for another way.